# Orchard CMS remove Home menu link when adding title of the page to the menu

Tags: orchardcms

I just created a new Orchard website. I added 5 articles to it and when I was done, I have 6 menu links.

[image]
See: http://www.where-to-find-gold.org/. Home and A Quick Look are the same page and same url. This was the first article I added and I just overwrote the content of the existing hello world page. I wanted the link text to be "A Quick Look" instead of "Home", so I clicked Show on main menu:

[image]

How do remove the "Home" link?

I had considered deleting the hello world page first and then adding my content, but It seems Orchard is still a bit rough around the edges and didn't want to risk anything that would crash the app like I have been seeing on a regular basis. Like, don't put a dot in table prefix or the site will crash. Don't put "http://" in the url when creating the Tenant site, ditto on the crash. Anyways, any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your menu through the Navigation link in the Orchard dashboard. Just delete the extra item from the menu there and your menu should look like what you want it to look like.

And of course, if you want to be safe, make a database backup before doing so, even though I don't think that would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup first and then try it. This way, you're safe.